# credit card information display in a magento 2 controller

Tags: magento2

credit card information display in a magento 2 controller[image]

Comment: What is the actual question here ?

Comment: i want above card information's post in a custom controller

Comment: Which payment module are you using to display the payment form ? Also please take care about PCI DSS... you need to take a whole lot of care if you want to handle creditcard data yourself